# Windows 8 GridView events

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8, windows-8.1

is there a way to detect when one of the items containing in the GridView scrolls into view?
I wan't to create some effects for not in the view && not on lead position items.

Example:

In this position i wan't dimmed Group 2,3+, but Group 1 - highlighted

But when user will scroll to Group 3 - it becomes highlighted etc.

Is there some sort of event that i can add to items in GridView - like ItemmScrolledIntoView()?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `GridView` does not have a simple way of doing this. You'll need to make a custom `GridView` or possibly not use a `GridView`.

One option that would make this easier is to base your implementation on a `Hub` control. The `Hub` control has the `SectionsInView` property (including the ability to get the first item from this list) along with the `SectionsInViewChanged` event. I think it's likely that you will combine these two in this way:

In your ViewModel, create a `FirstSection` property which stores the first entry in the `SectionsInView` list. Have the `HubSection`s bind an overlay (or their Opacity) or current VisualState to this value.

Then, in the `SectionsInViewChanged` event, update your `ViewModel` and notify the change. If you did the changes (such as to opacity) through binding/converters, this should be immediate. Otherwise, you'll need to change the VisualState manually, but it's still not particularly hard. Especially because you can only change the values of `SectionsInView` (that aren't the first value).

The latter part can be an option on its own, but may have some performance issues, especially when scrolling quickly.